# sapui5 version 1.108 showing scrolling table does not load data dynamically

Tags: sapui5

when i scroll up and come down then only the data loads more.
it does not do dynamically if i scroll down.

i used threshold and growing property, it does not help

```
<t:Table
            rows="{
                path: 'OData>/Users',
                parameters:{
                    $select: 'id,groupname,groupid,role,lastactivity,inactivity,expirydate',
                    $orderby:'id asc'
                    }
                }"
            threshold="200"
            id="itemsTable"
            enableCellFilter="true"
            selectionMode="Single"
            selectionBehavior="RowOnly"
            showColumnVisibilityMenu="true"
            enableScrolling="true"
            rowSelectionChange="handleDetailsPress"
            visibleRowCountMode="Auto">
            <t:columns>
```